# socket.io two client versions

Tags: socket.io, package.json

We have two microservices with different versions of the server and we need to connect to them. Initially there was a client of version 3, then we added a client of version 2 and 3 stopped working, because they use different version of socket-io-parser.

package.json

```
"socket.io-client2": "npm:socket.io-client@2.4.0",
"socket.io-client3": "npm:socket.io-client@3.1.3",
```

error in browser

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading'CONNECT') in socket.js

        
this.packet({ type: socket_io_parser_1.PacketType.CONNECT, data: this.auth });
```

PacketType not exist in socket.io-parser@3.3.2

How to resolve this conflict and use two versions?

Comment: 'socket-io-client3' has its own version of the 'socket-io-parser' in the 'node-modules' inside package, but for some reason it connects to the 'socket-io-parser' from the main 'node-modules' directory, is it possible that the webpack is configured incorrectly?

Answer (score 0):

Solved the problem by fixing the configuration of the Webpack.
I Added 'node_modules' in section resolve -> modules

use this doc: https://webpack.js.org/configuration/resolve/#resolvemodules

```
  resolve: {
    modules: ['node_modules']
  }
```